# Clean - Appending to a list

Tags: functional-programming

I am trying to append to a list in the [Clean programming language](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean).

This is my code:

```
import StdEnv

path0 = "urrd"
//path1 = "urdl"
//path2 = "uurrddll"
//path3 = "ururdrdldlul"

Mirror :: [Char] -> [Char]

Mirror [] = []
Mirror str = [(NegatePath last str) : (Mirror init str)]

NegatePath :: Char -> Char

NegatePath 'u' = 'd'
NegatePath 'd' = 'u'
NegatePath 'l' = 'r'
NegatePath 'r' = 'l'

Start = Mirror path0
```

This is the error I get:

Type error [Homokozoo.icl,13,Mirror]:"argument 1 of list constructor" cannot unify types:
[Char]
{#Char}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know about the Clean language before reading this question, so this could be way off, but I think I've identified the problem after spending some time scanning chapter 4 of the language report.  The problem appears to be that your `Mirror` function is built to operate on a list of characters `[Char]` but you are passing it an unboxed array of characters `{#Char}`.

It might work if you declared

```
path0 = ['urrd']
```

so that the type of `path0` is a list of characters rather than an unboxed array of characters.  If that's not what you want, you may need to modify the `Mirror` function to work on `{Char}`.

Comment: I have my input given as a String, I can't change that. I can rewrite my function to work on a list of chars instead of an array of them, however I was not yet able to find a way of converting an array to a list.

This does not work for some reason:

    
toList array = [e \\ e <- array]